# Why Delphi IDE also Contains .NET Code instead of just Object Pascal

Tags: delphi

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why are there so many $IF DEFINED(CLR) in the VCL/RTL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2210122/why-are-there-so-many-if-definedclr-in-the-vcl-rtl)

I know Delphi 7 Was Written in Object Pascal(Delphi) but since Delphi 8, released December 2003, was a .NET-only release that compiled Delphi Object Pascal code into .NET CIL; the IDE was rewritten for this purpose.

Comment: [Allen Bauer](http://stackoverflow.com/users/20552/allen-bauer) explain this in a old S.O question [Why are there so many $IF DEFINED(CLR) in the VCL/RTL?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2210122/why-are-there-so-many-if-definedclr-in-the-vcl-rtl).

Comment: @Rruz, although Bauer explains in his answer that the IDE was developed for .Net, the question is not a duplicate. That question asks why the VCL source code contains conditional code for .Net. *This* question asks why the IDE has .Net code in it; it's not a question of the VCL source code included in the Delphi installation directory.

Comment: Just because Delphi is a program, doesn't make asking Why a closed-source binary application that nobody on here (other than 1 or 2 embarcadero employees) has source code to, contains X or Y, is not on topic per the FAQ, any more than asking, why Excel contains (or does not contain) .Net, or ActiveX, or whatever. At least the linked duplicate was about some code you could inspect. This question calls for speculation, and has no technical answer germane to the FAQ.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The IDE contains .Net code because the IDE is, at least in part, a .Net application. That's completely independent of the binaries that the compiler produces from your source code.

Although the Delphi IDE helps you develop Delphi applications, that doesn't mean the development tools all need to be written in that language. Portions are written in C++, C#, and assembler, too.